# Symfony - redirect client to new route through event subscriber

Tags: javascript, php, html, symfony, twig

I'm trying to redirect clients sitting on a certain route, whenever another specific client presses a button in their view. My plan is this:

- Client 1 presses a button to invoke a request to route A
- Controller that defines route A invokes a method in service B
- Service B executes some other operations, then dispatches event C
- Subscriber of event C does ??? to redirect client 2 & 3, who are currently both on route D, to route E

I'm unsure, whether it's actually possible to redirect clients based on the route they are on or whether I need to store some sort of session information to reference each client that needs to be redirected.

Comment: Instead of listening for event C, it might be possible to use a [kernel response listener](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-response) to generate your redirect.  It is a bit hard to say for sure based on your description.

Comment: The description of kernel response listener doesn't sound that helpful for my case. I just need a way to change what is being displayed to a client based on the behavior of another client. I could just send requests to the server every X seconds to check, whether the client has to change route, but using events/listeners seems like better practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic symfony can't do this. In order to have this kind of communication between clients, websockets are needed. See https://packagist.org/packages/gos/web-socket-bundle